# jQuery 1.8.1 erroring out in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 using jQuery 1.8.1 I keep getting the following error:

```
Line: 4230
Error: Failed
```

Here is that line in the jQuery lib:

```
    "TAG": function( nodeName ) {
        if ( nodeName === "*" ) {
            return function() { return true; };
        }
        nodeName = nodeName.replace( rbackslash, "" ).toLowerCase();

        return function( elem ) {
            return elem && elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === nodeName;
        }; // Line 4130

    },
```

This has got me stumped for 2 days now... anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Where is your code that's calling this? i'm not getting this error in IE7.

Comment: Its being included in the body of the HTML...

Comment: The issue should not be related to jQuery, your script that is calling jQuery is the culprit.

Comment: I think I have the culprit located... it looks like its jQuery_ujs (Rails.js)

Comment: Out of curiosity @dennismonsewicz, what was it in Rails.js causing this? I'm having a similar issue where jQuery is giving me "FAILED" in IE7... I can't reproduce it though, so it's tough to fix haha

Comment: I need to amend my answer, because it wound up being a library (or file) called PIE.htc